# I received an error when joining data through JoinRowSet

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I've tried to do a Join via Java using JoinRowSet but with no success, i'm receiving an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Match Column not set for join
at com.sun.rowset.JoinRowSetImpl.addRowSet(JoinRowSetImpl.java:219)
at joinrowset.JoinRowSet.databaseCheck(JoinRowSet.java:33)
at joinrowset.JoinRowSet.main(JoinRowSet.java:49)
```

What is the solution to this problem ? i can't find anything on the internet so i'm stuck. If you have a solution it would be great. Thanks

```
package joinrowset;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;



public class JoinRowSet {


    void databaseCheck() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {


        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Movies;integratedSecurity=true";
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement s = c.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select FilmName from tblFilm");

        CachedRowSet director = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
        CachedRowSet film = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();

        director.populate(s.executeQuery("select DirectorName from tblDirector"));
        film.populate(s.executeQuery("select FilmName from tblFilm"));

        javax.sql.rowset.JoinRowSet jrs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createJoinRowSet();
        jrs.addRowSet(director);
        jrs.addRowSet(film);

        while(jrs.next()) {
            for(int i=1; i<=jrs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {

                System.out.println(jrs.getString(i) + "\t");
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        JoinRowSet instantiate = new JoinRowSet();
        instantiate.databaseCheck();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JoinRowSet wants to know, how to join your data. You need to set a match column. 
In queries `select DirectorName from tblDirector` and `select FilmName from tblFilm` there isn't a column which could be used as a match column.
I guess every film has to have a director and, probably, in your table `tblDirector` you may find references for directors. In this case you could  rewrite the code as

```
director.populate(s.executeQuery("select DirectorName from tblDirector"));
film.populate(s.executeQuery("select FilmName, DirectorName from tblFilm"));
javax.sql.rowset.JoinRowSet jrs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createJoinRowSet();

director.setMatchColumn(1);   //position of the column "DirectorName" 
film.setMatchColumn(2);       //position of the column "DirectorName" 

jrs.addRowSet(director);
jrs.addRowSet(film);
```

Do not forget, it's just an example based on my assumption about your data structure.

Comment: Both of the columns (directorName and FilmName) are in the first position of the tables. The error had dissapeared....but i think i did not iterate correctly through JoinRowSet..... after i've done what you said, there is no result in the output :( . This is the code modified as you said. The book from which i've took this example may be outdated. Any example how to iterate correctly through a join row set ? (i assume that bad iteration may be the problem) . The iteration is the same as in my initial question about this subject.